# Where can I find part number for OEM replacement wiper blades or inserts for Mercedes?

Tags: mercedes-benz, part-identification, parts, windshield-wipers

I'd like to replace the windshield wiper blades (or better yet just the inserts) on the original Mercedes C-300 2014 with VIN Beginning WDDGF8AB5ER....  I used Amazon garage to find ones that supposedly fit and ordered them, but when they came, they definitely do not fit, completely different mounting mechanism.  The Amazon recommended ones were: [Valeo 900245B Frameless ULTIMATE 24" All-Season OE Replacement Wiper Blade](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000LV7XP8) based the following in the Amazon garage:

```
2014 Mercedes-Benz C300 Vehicle Info:

Trim: 4Matic Sport
Bed: N/A
Body Style: 4 Door Sedan
Brakes: Power Front/Rear Disc, 4-Wheel ABS
Drive Type: All-Wheel Drive
Engine: 3.5L V6 Gas
Mfr Body Code: 204.080
Spring Types: Front/Rear Coil
Steering: Power Rack
Transmission: Mercedes-Benz 7-Speed Automatic Transmission 722.9
Wheelbase: N/A
```

How can I locate the exact part numbers for these?

Comment: Sorry to have to close this, as I understand your plight. You might try and ask this over on [The Pitstop](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/340/the-pitstop), Mechanics.SE's main chat room, as we have a lot more flexibility there to talk about purchases/shopping and such.

Comment: Go to a Mercedes main dealer.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 I would think finding the exact part number (not price) would be on topic, right?

Comment: I'd buy that :o) (pun intended).